# Stored Procedure for dynamic value in column

Tags: postgresql, function

My sample input text is 'IG_ASE_APAC'

I need to write a procedure to match the input value and return true or false.

My input text has some conditions :

1. The input string length is fixed to 3 (separated by _)
2. The first word remains the same IG
3. The second word can be anything from this list (ASE, BSE, DSE)
4. The third word can be (APAC, FADF, GHFE)

my result should satisfy the 4 conditions:

```
    IG_ASE_APAC - true 
    IG_DSE_APAC - true 
    IL_ASE_APAC - false 
    IG_BSE_FADF - true
```

I'm very new to the stored procedures. I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: so what do you have so far?

Comment: I was able to do this SELECT column
 FROM table where 
 column similar to 'IP%'

Comment: OK, well it sounds like you (1) need to read the manuals and identify the built-in functions for splitting strings on "_" and then package that up in an sql or plpgsql function https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html

Answer (score 1):

Since your rules are quite specific you can get what you are after with a single query with a regular expression.

```
with test(val) as
     ( values ('IG_ASE_APAC')
            , ('IG_DSE_APAC')
            , ('IL_ASE_APAC')
            , ('IG_BSE_FADF')
     )
select val, val ~ '^IG_(ASE|BSE|DSE)_(APAC|FADF|GHFE)$'  pattern_ok  
  from test;
```

If you really *need* a stored procedure (well actually function). Apply the regular expression within an SQL function that returns a boolean, then call that function for each string you need to test.  (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=a52af669d871f2c35fcc73789818c982)).

```
create or replace 
function is_valid_pattern(string_in text) 
    returns boolean 
   language sql 
as $$
   select string_in ~ '^IG_(ASE|BSE|DSE)_(APAC|FADF|GHFE)$';
$$;
```

I will leave it to your research for how the regular expression and the function itself work. It is all in the documentation.